# Why "\r " deletes my previous printed line but "\r" it doesn't

Tags: c, printf, carriage-return

When I print some line, if I want to overwrite for example the first character, I use `\r` because is the carriage return character but it prints only one character after this one, my whole line is overwritten.

This is some code that I made for this question.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

    printf("-------");
    printf("\r ");
    return 0;

}
```

using this code my output is:  with one space.

Now I change a little bit the code. The only change is that in my second `printf` I delete the space after `\r`

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

    printf("-------");
    printf("\r");
    return 0;

}
```

using this second code my output is `"-------"` (without quotes)

my expected output: `" ------"`

Why this is not working?

Comment: Whatever terminal you're using probably deletes the entire line when you start printing to the same line. A carriage return without a newline might start overwriting the same line.

Comment: The C standard (and by extension `printf`) doesn't dictate this behaviour, so this is really more of a question about your terminal.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`\r` is Carriage Return.  It sends the "carriage" (cursor, in modern times) back to the beginning of the same line.  It does not by itself erase anything--just moves the cursor.  Apparently your terminal has the behavior that printing a character at the beginning of a line erases the rest of the line.  That's not guaranteed, I think.

On many systems if you want to clear the current line you must print `\r` followed by as many spaces as the line had characters on it.

Comment: This is the same for other characters as well.

Comment: Sorry to be a nitpick, but it also will happen with two (or more...) characters. And what happens is the everything is written, but then the terminal overwrites starting from the end of the initial string. If "-----------------------" would have been long enough (longer than the prompt) the end would still be visible.

Comment: @kabanus: A fine point, maybe the reason OP sees this behavior is that their prompt is overwriting the rest of the line.  Again, this depends on the terminal emulator...but certainly if you actually want to erase a line you need to overwrite all its characters.